# Return value of after running sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart command

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there any way to find the return value after I restart Apache Web server using the following command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

So that I can check whether Apache restart was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Three ways.

First, the variable `$?` holds the return code of the last shell command.  So you can do

```
echo $?
```

and hope for a zero.

Second, you can scan the last few lines of the `error_log` and confirm that Apache started successfully.  (`tail -n 5 error_log`) prints the last 5 lines; now just `grep` that output for a success string of your choosing.

```
tail -n 5 /my/path/error_log | grep 'resuming normal operations'
```

Third, you can list running processes and verify that the `httpd` process is running.

```
ps -u apacheuser -U apacheuser | grep apache2
```

where `apacheuser` is the user your server is configured to run as.

Comment: Isn't there any more specific command to get the return Value?
What do you mean by the last shell command?

Comment: What kind of specificity are you looking for? Any process, when it exits, returns an integer as its exit code.  Traditionally, zero means success, and any other value indicates an error.

Comment: It's exactly what it sounds like... the last command that was processed. If you open up and read /etc/init.d/apache2 and look at the 'restart' case, you can see exactly what it's doing. After a command runs, it updates the $? variable with a number, 0 meaning success and anything higher having custom meanings depending on the software.

Comment: Or if you can find someone that knows a little more about shell scripting you can edit the /etc/init.d/apache2 file to be a little more verbose during each step of the restart process